# How can I make data in my Android application searchable through S Finder and Google Now?

Tags: android, indexing, google-now

How can I make data in my application searchable through S Finder and Google Now? I can't find a way to do that.  Thanks.

Comment: [This](http://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/index.html) might be helpful.

Comment: Had found it before, but thanks anyway. 
Do not know if it's the same for the S Finder, a simple introduction on the subject would be enough for me to move on.